# Select query with Date of Today not working

Tags: codeigniter, date, select

I'm trying to select from table Documents where Date is Today's date. I'm using Codeigniter. 
But it shows only these documents where there isn't hour. I mean where in database date is: 2015-06-25 00:00:00. But it doesn't display these documents where there is an hour - for example : 2015-06-25 08:34:00.
How to display all documents where Date is current date , no matter what is the hour.

```html
<?php
 $date = new DateTime("now");
 
 $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('documents'); 
 $this->db->where('Date', $curr_date);
 $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Assume your Date is the field name- that's bad practice to start with. You could try where('DATE(Date)', $curr_date) to ignore the time component. Not sure how code igniter works with MySQL functions but worth a go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime("now");

 $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d ');

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('documents'); 
 $this->db->where('DATE(Date)',$curr_date);//use date function
 $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

[MySQL date Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp)

Comment: Don't use DATE function, as it will call it for every single record. Doing between like query is the way to go, i.e. `Date >= 'X 00:00:00' AND Date < 'X+1 day 00:00:00'`

Comment: @SoulReaver Read the question before you post something. +When searching the exact day is more efficient using the `WHERE` clause rather than `LIKE`.

Comment: I had `WHERE` clause in mind all the time. I've meant beetween-like query not LIKE query.

Comment: @SoulReaver if its `DateTime` column `BETWEEN` must use. If `DATE` column no use of `BETWEEN`

Comment: Let me rephrase that. I had in mind a query like `BETWEEN`, i.e. one that uses `<` and `=>` (which I already wrote in my very first comment) and not a query that uses `BETWEEN` or `LIKE`. Not my fault that query language uses actual English words.