# fetch data from database based on date

Tags: codeigniter

This is my table fields
**table1 : cash_transactions**
id
dated_on
amount
from_user
to_user
trans_type
userid
purpose
**table2 : login**
loginid
name
username
password
usertype
status

Controller : Admin

```
public function daily_report()
{
    $daily_date=date('Y-m-d');
    $data['fetch']= $this->admin->get_daily_report($daily_date);
    $this->load->view('daily_report',$data);

}
```

Model: Admin_Model

```
public function get_daily_report($daily_date)
{
    $this->db->select('c.userid,c.amount,c.trans_type,c.from_user,c.to_user,c.purpose,l.loginid,l.name');
    $this->db->from('cash_transactions as c');
    $this->db->join('login as l', 'c.userid = l.loginid');
    $this->db->where('c.dated_on',$daily_date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result =$query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Here i want to fetch the current date data from the database, but this is not working. Please solve this problem.

Comment: `ìt is not working`? define your problem. you got any error? you have rows when you run the query in the database?

Comment: Array ( [fetch] => Array ( ) ) - i got output as like this without no values

Comment: can you show your view page?

Comment: dont got any error when i run it.

Comment: i just print out this output. doesn't load the data to view

Comment: and your view page?

Comment: @ManjushaKVijayan make sure date in your database and in the variable have the same format also

Comment: yes the date in the same format.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047890/select-query-with-date-of-today-not-working . I believe this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

Controller : Admin

```
public function daily_report()
{
    $daily_date=date('Y-m-d');
    $data['fetch']= $this->admin->get_daily_report($daily_date);
    $this->load->view('daily_report',$data);

}
```

Model: Admin_Model

```
public function get_daily_report($daily_date)
{
    $this->db->select('c.userid,c.dated_on,c.amount,c.trans_type,c.from_user,c.to_user,c.purpose,l.loginid,l.name');
    $this->db->from('cash_transactions as c');
    $this->db->join('login as l', 'c.userid = l.loginid');
    $this->db->where('c.dated_on',$daily_date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result =$query->result();
    return $result;
}
```